# Suggestion of friends ordered by mutual friends on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I've the following table

**friendship**:

```
id | friend_one | friend_two | status | date
1  | 1          | 2          | 2      | 10/06/2016
3  | 2          | 3          | 2      | 10/06/2016
4  | 2          | 4          | 2      | 10/06/2016
5  | 2          | 5          | 2      | 10/06/2016
6  | 4          | 5          | 2      | 10/06/2016
7  | 3          | 4          | 2      | 10/06/2016
8  | 3          | 7          | 2      | 10/06/2016
9  | 5          | 1          | 2      | 10/06/2016
10 | 6          | 4          | 2      | 10/06/2016
11 | 6          | 1          | 2      | 10/06/2016
```

In `friendship` table, `status = 2` means that they are friends and the `friend_one` is the user that send the friend request.

And I want to get suggestions of friends based to the mutual friends count, that is, the more friends in common, the greater the chance of being recommended to me (user logged).

For this, I thought of the following:

1. Select all my friends, then
2. Select all friends of my friends (deleting myself), then
3. Check if friends of my friends are not my friends, then
4. Suggest to friend (order by mutual friends count)

But, I can not put it into practice. To achieve the first step, I started with (taking into account that the `id` of user logged is 1):

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN a.friend_one = 1 THEN a.friend_two ELSE a.friend_one END AS myFriend
FROM friendship a
WHERE 1 IN(a.friend_one, a.friend_two) AND a.status = 2
```

And so I can select all the friends of the user with id 1.

To achieve the second step, I did:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN a.friend_one = 1 THEN a.friend_two ELSE a.friend_one END AS myFriend, 
CASE WHEN b.friend_one = myFriend THEN b.friend_two ELSE b.friend_one END AS friendFriend 
FROM friendship a 
LEFT JOIN friendship b ON myFriend IN (b.friend_one, b.friend_two) AND b.status = 2
WHERE 1 IN(a.friend_one, a.friend_two) AND a.status = 2
```

So, I get the error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'myFriend' in 'field list'

But, I do not know how to continue. The four steps I thought were correct? If so, how do I "fix" the error and get friends suggestions on the basis of the number of mutual friends?

Desired result:
4 (3 mutual friends), 3 (1 mutual friend)

Comment: According your elaboration, friend to be suggested is `5, 3, 4`? Or can you please post your desired result?

Comment: @Forward I edited the table to be easier to present the desired result and added the desired result in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You established the `myFriend` alias as the first column of the SELECT clause in your second step; you cannot use that alias as a source for other columns in the same SELECT clause.  You will have to repeat the CASE statement in its place.  Alternatively, you can compute `myFriend` in a subquery and reference it by name in some places.

This is only a response to the error message you're getting, not a check of your complete algorithm.